# Does $\sqrt[3^5-1]{3}$ exist in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (or, $\mathbb{Q}_3)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to see whether $\sqrt[3^5-1]{3}$ exist in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (or, $\mathbb{Q}_3)$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of integers of the p-adic field.

If it exist then let $x=\sqrt[3^5-1]{3}$ which implies $x^{243}-3x=0$.

We have $x^{243} \equiv 0$ (mod $3$) but it's first derivative is not zero modulo $3$. So we can not use Hensel lemma

Is there other ways to see it ?

Comment: First you should add to the post that $\Bbb Z_3$ is the ring of $3$-adic integers. Most of the users here use this differently, although the context of $\Bbb Q_3$ should make it clear.

Comment: You forgot one hypothesis about Hensel’s lemma – invalidating your reasoning. There’s also an easy ramification obstruction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Mindlack, thanks. Indeed I forgot to check the second hypothesis of Hensel. The valuation of $\sqrt[3^5-1]{3}$ is $\frac{1}{242}$. What does it tell as you mentioned ramification obstruction ?

Comment: Because Mindlack knows this stuff better than I do may be I should not comment. Nevertheless, I think the ramification obstruction they brought up is exactly that the valuation is $1/242$ as opposed to an integer.

Comment: Another way of phrasing the ramification obstruction is to use Eisenstein's lemma to see that $ X^{3^5 - 1} - 3  $ is irreducible. It's really the same argument, but putting it like this may be more familiar to you.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: that’s indeed what I had in mind (also, I don’t think I know this stuff better than you do, so don’t worry about commenting in my stead).

Comment: So the upshot of all comments is that that element doesn't belong to the p-sdic integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extending comments to an answer:

No "proper" root of $p$, i.e. an element we would call $\sqrt[n]{p}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N_{\ge 2}$, exists in $\mathbb Q_p$.

That is for the simple reason that the $p$-adic valuation satisfies $v_p(x\cdot y)= v_p(x) +v_p(y)$, so that $v_p(\sqrt[n]{p})$ would need to be $\frac1n$; but $v_p(x) \in \mathbb Z$ for all $x \in \mathbb Q_p^*$.

Slightly more generally: If $a \in \mathbb Q_p$ is arbitrary, for the equation $X^n =a$ to have a solution in $\mathbb Q_p$ it is necessary that $n \vert v_p(a)$. (It is not sufficient in general.)

Comment: Right: this was my first reaction to the title here.